# need a way to get my host socket to be controlled by my client host which is a mobile device

Tags: socket.io

I am using socket io to control a text editor from a mobile phone but i am a little confused on how to add socket io to the server and control the host text editor browser from the the client browser.
I have read the doc on the website but i am unable to find out how to control a browser from an html keypad on the mobile.

Comment: Use the, onkeypress event and emit a new event from the client to the server (the data would be the char pressed) and catch on in the server, is that what you want ?

Comment: yes actually thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the, onkeypress event and emit a new event from the client to the server (the data would be the char pressed) and catch on in the server.

```
input.keypress( function(evt){
   var key = //get the pressed key
   socket.emit( 'keyPressed', {key: key});
})
```

Comment: thanks ayrton this really did help. i am a noob at sockets.io